# Python 2 :Simple Program

Tags: python, syntax-error, raw-input

I want to make a program something like password program.
When words entered by the user are the same words that I give to the program, it should print "Done", otherwise "Wrong".

```
x = raw_input("Enter Your name:")
y = raw_input("Enter Your L name:")
if x=Sajad and y=Ha:
    print "Done"
else:
    print "Wrong"
```

Python tells me "Invalid Syntax".
I gave a value for Sajad and Ha,
but still it does not work.
(I don't want to use any lists.)

Comment: Use **==** for comparison

Comment: And if you want to compare x/y with strings don't forget the enclosing `"` (`x=='Sajad' and y=='Ha'`), unless `Sajad` and `Ha` are intended to be variables.

Answer (score 1):

Man , it's not a good question .

Go through the [Python 2.7 Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) Or [Python 3.x Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) seriously and write your program again .

If you still don't know how to do that .
Answer is [here](https://gist.github.com/KIDJourney/fe425c0fd35386227bda)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = raw_input("Enter Your name:")
y = raw_input("Enter Your L name:")
if x=='Sajad' and y=='Ha':
    print("Done")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

All errors in line `if x=Sajad and y=Ha:`

1) x=1 is assignment. x==1 is comparsion. Use `==` here. (read about difference between `is` and `==`)

2) `Sajad` is string, thats why you should use quotes

Final code is:

```
x = raw_input("Enter Your name:")
y = raw_input("Enter Your L name:")
if x=="Sajad" and y=="Ha":
    print "Done"
else:
    print "Wrong"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Python comparison operators in an 'IF' statement. 
Change your code to this to get the output you desire.

```
x = raw_input("Enter Your name:")
y = raw_input("Enter Your L name:")
if x==Sajad and y==Ha:
    print "Done"
else:
    print "Wrong"
```